# Intune problems on Windows

Tags: java, windows, intune, scep

I'm using Intune on Windows. Among others there needs to be generated a certificate via the SCEP protocol. Therefore we implemented a SCEP-CA-adapter that implements the SCEP-Server protocol. On syncing Windows, the SCEP process gets triggered.

The adapter receives GetCACaps and GetCACert and afterward starts a PKCS_REQ request. So the certification request (containing a valid CSR) starts. But as a result, the adapter first answers using PENDING signaling that the certificate is in the creation process.

But the DeviceManagement on Windows instantly stops the process. On analysing the event logs there could only be found the following line:

```
scep certificate enroll failed. result (the requested property value is empty.)
```

I don't know what property the error is referring to.

What's going wrong, or where I can further find information on the issue? We are kind of stuck.

The adapter works fine on apple and android.

I tried to fill the PENDING reply with SignedData, tried to go through the Windows event logs.

Thanks in advance